# How to launch Outlook Web AddIn on selection of email, instead of launching the AddIn on every email?

Tags: outlook-web-addins

Outlook Web Add-in is not loading automatically on selection of email, How to launch the Outlook Web AddIn automatically on selection of email ?

Answer (score 0):

Read this: [Implement a pinnable task pane in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/pinnable-taskpane)